# comparing a model field with choices to a string

Tags: python, django

Struggling a bit with something that should work and can't figure out why it doesn't.

I'm using Django 3.1.5, Python 3.9.1

Simplified version:

```
addresses/models.py:

  SHIPPING_CHOICES = (
        ('standard', '$4.50 > 2-5 business days'),
        ('tracked ', '$5.50 > 2-5 business days'),  
        ('rural', '$8.50 > 3-6 business days'),
    )
    class Address(models.Model):
        shipping_option = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='standard',
                                           choices=SHIPPING_CHOICES)
```

---

```
orders/models.py

class Order(models.Model):
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="shipping_address",
                                         null=True, blank=True, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)

def update_total(self):
    if self.shipping_address is not None:   
        if self.shipping_address.shipping_option == "tracked":
             shipping_total = 5.50
```

Problem is that the comparismant

> if self.shipping_address.shipping_option == "tracked":

never gives true when I choose tracked as the shipping option in this example.

From reading other questions I know that "is" would be wrong here to use and it can only be "==" for the two strings.
I've checked the type of "self.shipping_address.shipping_option" output and did print to double check the value that comes trough is the same as in the if clause.

Thoughts on what could be going here?

---

**Update**

simple spelling mistake at SHIPPING_CHOICES. 'tracked ' instead of 'tracked'

Comment: `('tracked ', '$5.50 > 2-5 business days'),` notice the space after `tracked`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your choices definition `'tracked '` notice the extra space. In general instead of comparing with strings everywhere it is best to declare constants in the class and use them. Quoted from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> Generally, it’s best to define choices inside a model class, and to
> define a suitably-named constant for each value

Hence you should change your implementation to:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    STANDARD = 'standard'
    TRACKED = 'tracked'
    RURAL = 'rural'
    SHIPPING_CHOICES = (
        (STANDARD, '$4.50 > 2-5 business days'),
        (TRACKED, '$5.50 > 2-5 business days'),  
        (RURAL, '$8.50 > 3-6 business days'),
    )
    shipping_option = models.CharField(
        max_length=120, default=STANDARD, choices=SHIPPING_CHOICES
    )
```

Now in your method:

```
def update_total(self):
    if self.shipping_address is not None:   
        if self.shipping_address.shipping_option == self.shipping_address.TRACKED:
             shipping_total = 5.50
```

This would reduce the chances of magic strings causing typos.

Comment: @Tobstar the issue is you already have instances in your database where `shipping_option` is stored as `'tracked '` you need to fix that. A query like `Address.objects.filter(shipping_option='tracked ').update(shipping_option='tracked')` in the shell should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, you are the man. Once I've realised that you had already answered. Creating a new instance was the way to go about it.